# Weird behavior when changing ringer mode normal to silent in android 8

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-8.0-oreo

In my app, I have 3 radio button for letting user changing ringer mode of the device. But from android 8 I'm facing one weird issue.

When ringer mode is set from **Normal** to **Silent** touch **sound** is still heard. This is not intended behavior.

But when ringer mode is changed from **Normal** to **Vibrate** and then **Vibrate** to **Silent**. Touch sound is **not** heard. This is intended behavior for my app

Now my question why this is happening in Normal to Silent mode.

*This are my code for changing ringer mode*

Permission for OS 7 and above

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

In my code, I have checked if the user gave me the **ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY** permission and if not move him to **ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS** for giving me the permission and after that I let the user change the setting.

```
public static void setMannerMode(Context context, int ringerMode) {
        try {
            AudioManager auManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            auManager.setRingerMode(ringerMode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed the mode like this according to checked radio button

```
Util.setMannerMode(getApplicationContext(), AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

or

```
Util.setMannerMode(getApplicationContext(), AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

or

```
Util.setMannerMode(getApplicationContext(), AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Comment: Whoever down vote this question , can you specify the reason please ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have fixed this touch sound issue while on **SILENT** mode on **OS 8** is by setting `NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE` in `NotificationManager`

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);
```

More info on interruption filter can be found [NotificationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html)